# What is the correct way to expand a variable that contains other variable definitions in front of a command?

Tags: bash

To be specific, consider the case:

```
MY_OPT_OPTIONS='CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native" CPPFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native"'
```

Now I want to execute g++ with these:

```
"$MY_OPT_OPTIONS" gcc ...
```

But this results in the error:

```
CFLAGS="-O3: command not found
```

All I want is for the `MY_OPT_OPTIONS` variable to be literally expanded in-line and for gcc to be executed with its other command line parameters.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but complex cases fail!"

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you don't. Pre-command assignments are recognized before parameter expansion. You would have to use the `env` command:

```
# Wrong, but read on...
env "$MY_OPT_OPTIONS" gcc ...
```

so that the expansion occurs first, and the results are passed to `env`, which creates the necessary environment. However, `env` expects each assignment as a separate argument, which means you need to use an array for it to work properly.

```
MY_OPT_OPTIONS=(CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native" CPPFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native")

env "${MY_OPT_OPTIONS[@]}" gcc ...
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using A Function

In addition to [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674331/14122) using the external command `env` with an array, another option (relying only on shell-builtin functionality) is to use a function:

```
with_my_options() {
  CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native" CPPFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native" "$@"
}

with_my_options gcc ...
```

...which works because `"$@"` evaluates to your original command line exactly as-given.

---

#### Using A Trusted String

If you *really* want to use a trusted, audited string, it's also possible to jump through a bunch of hoops to use `eval` in such a way as to not incur security bugs from content other than that string:

```
with_trusted_string() {
  local trusted_prefix_str arg_str
  trusted_prefix_str=$1; shift        # store first argument in 'trusted_prefix_str' and pop
  printf -v arg_str '%q ' "$@"        # quote & concatenate remaining arguments into arg_str
  eval "$trusted_prefix_str $arg_str" # evaluate resulting value
}

with_trusted_str "$MY_OPT_OPTIONS" gcc ...
```

The above formulation generates `eval`-safe quoting for all arguments other than the first, which is prefixed directly to a string fed to `eval`.

<sub>Note that "trusted" is used above in the sense used in NSA security policy: A "trusted" component is one whose failure can cause the whole system to fail. Trusting things is thus undesirable by nature.</sub>